# Experimental support for decorators support error VSCODE?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, decorator

After installing Mobx for my create react app, and trying nearly every solution on the internet (editing TSconfig.json, setting decorators to true, restarting, moving tsconfig.json to project root directory) The error message still persists. Below is my code:

```
    import React from "react"; 
    import { Component } from 'react'
    import { observable} from "mobx";

     class SetupPage extends Component {
     @observable todos = []
      render() {


            return (
              <div> <h1>Test Code <h1> </div>
            );
        }

    }

export default SetupPage;
```

**Image of error:**

[image]

**Is there a definitive method to resolve this and therefore integrate mobx into a create react app?**

**EDIT Tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "ES6",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "esModuleInterop": true,


    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**Tsconfig.json's location in directory:**

[image]

**EDIT #2 Moving Tsconfig.json to root folder**:

[image]

**SRC folder is red because that's were the code snippet above is located**

Comment: Show us your tsconfig, and where is it in relation to your project?

Comment: Just added those files to the post

Comment: Put your config to project root, not to .vscode

Comment: That causes errors within the file I'll show you in the edit above